# How do I fix mesh shortening/scaling incorrectly when moved by an Armature

Tags: armature, transforms

When I move the part with pose mode, it shortens. I have an object with multiple disconnected parts. My hierarchy doesn't have any parts that are scaled.

[image: The hierarchy of my project]

My object looks like this:
[image: The object in the non-moved pose]

My object looks like this (in the moved state):
[image: The object in the moved pose, with the second part shortened]

Everything has a scale of 1, 1, 1.

Comment: hello please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Here: https://pasteall.org/blend/c359385dab96486b9674c90823a04a64. I should have thought of that, but whatever.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see if you select a vertex then open the *N panel > Item > Vertex Weights*, the vertices of this mesh are also assigned to the *Root* bone. Just select all these vertices and remove them from this group in the *Object Data panel > Vertex Groups > Remove*.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! So, does the root bone automatically control everything? I don't have to make a vertex group of all the parts, it already does that?

Comment: no it doesn't automatically control everything, it depends on how you've parented, for this kind of object parent With Empty Groups (which will create vertex groups but won't assign any vertex to them) then assign the vertices to the vertex group they are supposed to be part of